# Restart docker container from another container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up Docker with two containers. One is a web app and the second is a dnsmasq DHCP server.

Docker should update the dnsmasq container and the dhcp ip list from a event from the web app. The only option I have so far is to generate the dhcp hosts file and restart the dnsmasq container but it need to be done manually in the Docker host outside the web app container.

Is there a way to restart the service from another container?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to restart a container from another container would be to mount /var/run/docker.sock and use the API.  But I wouldn't do that from a webapp for obvious security reasons.

I would share the dhcp hosts file between the containers (with the `-v option`) and have a script running in the dnsmasq container that checks for changes in this file and restart the dnsmasq service in the container.  There's no need to restart the container.  You could use Supervisord to start dnsmasq and this script.  I would use the `--init` flag to avoid zombie process.

Comment: Usually, I do `kill -s SIGHUP <process_pid_here>` for many Unix processes to force it to reload config. But this could not be done with docker, so the dockerized application has to have an additional listening thread to listen for special custom actions. Sometimes, I thought of using `redis` as message queue between containers. So this whole inter-container communication is still dealt with several non-standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

From your host:

`docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name=xxx ubuntu bash`

`docker cp /usr/bin/docker xxx:/usr/bin/docker`

Go inside the container and check unresolved libs:

`ldd /usr/bin/docker`

Manually copy missing libs from host into container and setup including symlinks as required. In my case I had to:

`docker cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1 xxx:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1`

And then inside the container I had to:

`ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7`

Inside the container check again: `ldd /usr/bin/docker`  if all is well, you can now run `docker` inside the container.

Note, that `docker-compose` run right away when i copied from host to container. Only `docker` i had to copy the extra library and setup the symlinks.

Comment: how can I do those with docker-compose from Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Copying libs feels weird...couldn't you just install Docker inside the container like you would install anything else?